# I want to export a value from one file to another in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-router

This is my routes.js file

```
const express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router(),
    loginHandler = require('../handler/loginHandler'),

router.get('^/:userId/:userType/:sessId/:lang/:orgId/:merchantId/:domainId', loginHandler.returnURLForIframe)

module.exports = router;
```

This is my loginHandler.js

```
class LoginHandler {
    returnURLForIframe(req, res) {
      let url = process.env.COMM_BACKOFFICE_URL+`/${req.params.userId}/${req.params.userType}/${encodeURIComponent(req.params.sessId)}/${req.params.lang}/${req.params.orgId}/${req.params.merchantId}/${req.params.domainId}`;
      res.send({
         statusCode:0,
         message:"COMM BO URL",
         data:{
              url:url
            }
        });
    }
}


module.exports = new LoginHandler()
```

and This is my responseHandler.js

```
const loginHandler  = require('./loginHandler');

class ResponseHandler {

    
    getResponseFromCOMM(options,token, res){
        options.headers= {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
            'merchantId': 1
        }
    }

}

module.exports = new ResponseHandler();
```

All I want to do is export `req.params.merchantId` from **loginHandler.js** to **responseHandler.js** *ANYHOW*..

I have tried to replicate this issue on Glitch : [https://glitch.com/~turquoise-spiky-chrysanthemum](https://glitch.com/%7Eturquoise-spiky-chrysanthemum)

Comment: why not set it with res.set() before res.send()? it seems odd your adding a response layer but then doing the res.send somewhere else, if you keep with this method you would be better off using the next() from the middleware and setting needed params for the response in req

Comment: How to use `res.set()`?

Comment: im guessing `options.headers` is setting some response headers.. [res.set()](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.set) does the same. your issue is your doing res.send too early

Comment: @LawrenceCherone  Please elaborate and show a practical implementation. I added `res.set('merchantId', req.params.merchantId)` before `res.send()`

Answer (score 1):

Export reference only like so: `module.exports = LoginHandler`

LoginHandler.js

```js
class LoginHandler {
    returnURLForIframe(req, res) {
      let url = process.env.COMM_BACKOFFICE_URL+`/${req.params.userId}/${req.params.userType}/${encodeURIComponent(req.params.sessId)}/${req.params.lang}/${req.params.orgId}/${req.params.merchantId}/${req.params.domainId}`;
      res.send({
         statusCode:0,
         message:"COMM BO URL",
         data:{
              url:url
            }
        });
    }
}


module.exports = LoginHandler
```

same for ResponseHandler.js

```js
const loginHandler  = require('./loginHandler');

class ResponseHandler {

    
    getResponseFromCOMM(options,token, res){
        options.headers= {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
            'merchantId': 1
        }
    }

}

module.exports = ResponseHandler;
```

Then import and create instance of `loginHandler` in routes.js

```js
const express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router(),
    loginHandler = require('../handler/loginHandler'),
const loginHandlerInstance = new loginHandler()
router.get('^/:userId/:userType/:sessId/:lang/:orgId/:merchantId/:domainId', loginHandlerInstance.returnURLForIframe)

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: how does that solve setting `'merchantId': 1` from the `req.params.merchantId`?

Comment: Yes, and also I'm getting this `TypeError: loginHandler is not a constructor                                                                                  at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Acer\angularProjects\pamSetup\comm-channel-node-gateway\routes\routes.js:8:30)`

Comment: why do you need class?